# Can maven sortpom plugin affect a project's build result?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Can the [**Maven Sortpom Plugin**](http://code.google.com/p/sortpom/) affect the result of a project's build ?

Is it possible to have a project build fail just because the sortpom plugin was added ?

Comment: I don't think so, cause the pom file will be read into Java class model so the real order of elements is usually nothing which influence the build or result. There are only things like the order of executions blocks within the same life cyclce phase where the execution is based on the order in the pom. What brings you to your assumption?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I agree with you. I wouldn't have thought that the sort pom could affect the build result but couldn't find anything any authoritative reference for it or documentation around exactly what it sorts. The official documentation says that: "The default sort order is taken from the [Maven3 pom documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html)".

Comment: Are you seeing a project fail to build, or is this a hypothetical question?

Comment: This is a hypothetical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the order of the elements in a pom.xml file does not matter, so reordering elements should not affect the build.

But I know of two exceptions to this rule:

- Maven reads **dependencies** according to the order in the pom-file when compiling. Rearranging that order may affect the compilation output.
- If two plugins executes in the same phase, the order in pom-file will determine which **plugin** to execute first. Sorting the plugins may cause the compilation to fail if the result of one plugin is dependent on another.

The sortpom plugin does not sort either dependencies nor plugins by default. So I would say that the sortpom plugin should not affect the result of a projects build.

Answer (score 0):

It can fail a build:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.code.sortpom:maven-sortpom-plugin:2.3.0:sort (default) on project data-extractor: scm.team.company.corp: Unknown host scm.team-project.company.corp -> [Help 1]

The if the  file isn't found due to network problems, even when running with -o

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For example, you use:

1. `org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin`'s `reserve-network-port` goal in phase `pre-integration-test`
2. `org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin`'s `run` goal also in phase `pre-integration-test`

Now, `sortpom:sort` orders them around, and in maven-3, the order of the plugins are important. So if you configure a random port for tomcat through the `portName` feature of `reserve-network-port`, the system property won't be filled (at the point it is needed), as after the sort, the build-helper artifact is executed *AFTER* the `run` goal is invoked.

Example after a sorting:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>start-tomcat</id>
          <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <fork>true</fork>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
      <!-- ... -->
  </executions>
  <configuration>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <port>${tomcat.http.port}</port><!-- Oops, not set (yet)! -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- ... -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${build-helper.version}</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>reserve-tomcat-port</id>
          <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <portNames>
                  <portName>tomcat.http.port</portName><!-- Too late -->
              </portNames>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```